# How to implement an JsonResult method to pass by http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ extra parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, ajax-upload

The website http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ says that:

```
Sending additional params

To add a parameter that will be passed as a query string with each upload use params option.

var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    action: '/server-side.upload',
    // additional data to send, name-value pairs
    params: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2'
    }
});
```

My question is: How do I should implement

```
public JsonResult UploadFile(string qqfile, ????)
{

}
```

correctly to pass 'value1' and 'value2'?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the model binder for that. Create a class with properties, where the names of the properties are equal to the params you send:

```
public class UploadPostModel
{
    public string param1 {get;set;}
    public string param2 {get;set;}
}
```

In the action, use the Postmodel. The default model-binder will automatically populate the class.

```
public JsonResult UploadFile(string qqfile, UploadPostModel pm)
{
    //use the values
}
```

ofcourse you could also put the qqfile in the Model.

Answer (score 2):

```
public JsonResult UploadFile(string qqfile, string param1, string param2)
{

}
```